# Make a page printer friendly aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, master-pages

I'm making a pretty simple site using a masterpage and a header and left menu user control. When a user prints the page, I want it to only print the content. Is there a more efficient solution than creating a version of the page that isn't registered to the master page & user controls? Thanks!

Comment: this will help: [Printer Friendly Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718/best-way-to-make-a-printer-friendly-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries with "print" selectors is one common option.

```
@media print { 
    .header
    {
       display:none
    }
}
```

Check out documentation for details [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), [MSDN `@media rule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries)